Calculating Availability % in prometheus, ignoring downtime of X mins
We are polling our services to check if they are available or not using an exporter. The output of those probes are 1/0. Now, I've a requirement to calculate the Availability % which ignores any downtime less than 5mins.
To achieve this, I'm using below query which averages the values provided by the metric over a range with 5min moving window. Also, I use the range vectors only for values that are greater than 0, which means only 5 min windows where the avg was not 0 should be considered.
avg(avg_over_time(metric[$__range:5m]) > 0 ) * 100

The problem is this returns data which does not show the Availability % I'm expecting (ignoring downtimes less than 5min ones and inconsistent)
But, if I run the below query, I get the exact true Availability %.
avg(avg_over_time(metric[$__range])) * 100

So, I'm wondering if my query is wrong or the moving average is not working as expected.
